# How do I create a 3D cylindrical beaker from a 2D cross section?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've tried creating a 3D object using Illustrator CS6 > Effect > 3D > Revolve > [default settings] but this simply creates a pure cylinder.

Here is my 2D shape:

[image]

Here is what Illustrator produces using Effect > 3D > Revolve > [default settings]:

[image]

The first 2D object has a transparent background, but it looks like Illustrator is counting the white space as part of the object.

I imported the 2D object as a PNG from Fireworks export.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was to export the right half of my 2D shape from Fireworks as an `.AI` file, and then the revolve command worked.